# How transfer documents (not music/video/photo) from Mac to Tab S 10.5?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, macos

HELP:  Really stuck just can't seem find a solution to move documents (powerpoint etc) from my Mac to a new Galaxy Tab S 10.5 - nothing seems to work - any suggestions please (of course i can fall back on dropbox I suppose but why can't the device be seen as an external memory source same as the Galaxy Note??

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy Tab S 10.6 seems to use MTP as USB connection mode. Since Mac OS X doesn't support MTP, your Mac can't see your device. I suppose that your Note has Micro SD card installed, and your Tab doesn't. If your Tab has a Micro SD card, it might be able to connect with your Mac.

For your question, I suggest using Airdroid (the first version) or anything similar to it. Since it transfers your file via LAN, transfer speed is a lot faster. Hope this help ;)

Comment: Thanks for that yep the Tab also uses the micro-SD card - i've given airdroid a try seems to work well, thanks so much